# How to make a parabola in GeoGebra?

Tags: geometry, math-software

I need to make a parabola in GeoGebra. "Smallest" one is going to contain 3 points, while the "biggest" one is going to be defined by 9 points.

So if anyone could explain to me how to make a parabola (from 3, 5, 7, 9... points)? I tried to make parabola by using segments (and combining them), but that just seems too daunting and I don't get the curves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A general conic in the plane is determined by 5 points on it. You can't make a parabola that pass through more than 5 arbitrary points. In GeoGebra, if you have 5 points, there is already a button that let you construct a conic out of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> Trendpoly[A,B,C,...,2]

where A,B,C,... are your points and "2" is the degree of your function.
Be aware, that the parabola doesn't go through all your given points.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also be aware: This assumes that the parabola you want has a vertical axis of symmetry.

Comment: @ulead86: TrendPoly is the name in German. In English it's FitPoly: https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/FitPoly_Command